# Android APP crashes when i try to open a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

When i try to click the Verkauf button on my App it should open a new Activity, but it crashes and closes immediately. I tried many things like building the project new or clean it or different code to open the activity. But as far is I know this should work. Sorry for my bad english.

```
public class AndroVegiActivity extends Activity{

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_andro_vegi);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("at.spengergasse.androvegi.Verkauf"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The second activity's class

```
public class Verkauf extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verkauf_activity);
    }
}
```

The layout XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    style="@style/kopf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/heading"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/buttonStyle0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:text="@string/button_verkauf" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@style/buttonStyle0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_sortiment" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="@style/buttonStyle0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_sonstiges" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="@style/buttonStyle0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/button_ende" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/apple" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/vegi" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/sweetpepper" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="at.spengergasse.androvegi.Verkauf" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingVerkauf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading_verkauf"
        android:textAppearance="@style/kopf"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headingVerkauf"
        android:text="@string/text_datum"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/headingVerkauf"
        android:text="@string/button_schliessen" >

    </Button>


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relBox1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProdukt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_produkt"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="33dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relBox2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPreis"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.86"
        android:text="@string/text_preis"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/preis"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relBox3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGewicht"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.10"
        android:text="@string/text_gewicht"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/gewicht"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relBox4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBezahlen"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.10"
        android:text="@string/text_bezahlen"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bezahlen"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relBox5"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/reihe1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b1_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b4_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b7_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b0_text" >

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/reihe2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b2_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b5_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b8_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bp_text" >

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/reihe3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b2_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b5_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/b8_text" >

        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bleer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/reihe4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLoeschen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/b_loeschen" >

        </Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="126dp"
            android:text="@string/b_ok" >

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relBox7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relBox6"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGesamtpreis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_gesamtpreis"
        android:textColor="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The XML Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroVegiActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Verkauf"
        android:label="@string/heading_verkauf" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="at.spengergasse.androvegi.Verkauf" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure that your Verkauf `Activity` is located in the Android Manifest. Something like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="your.package.name">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroVegiActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Verkauf"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Secondly, you should start your own activities like this

```
StartActivity(new Intent(AndroVegiActivity.this, Verkauf.class));
```

instead of using an explicit `String` for the `Intent` action.

Comment: I have edited my post. I already have it in the Manifest and when i try this StartActivity(new Intent(this, Verkauf.class));  It says: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Verkauf>) is undefined

Comment: That is because the first parameter must be some `Context`. So try `StartActivity(AndroVegiActivity.this, Verkauf.class));` The `this` context in your example is View.OnClickListener so you have to use the Activities context.

Comment: i still get this error: The method StartActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: i changed it to startActivity now i get no errors but it still crashes when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(AndroVegiActivity.this, Verkauf.class);// you can use getbasecontect()
  StartActivity(i);
```

Also define your activity in manifest file

`<activity android:name=".Verkauf"></activity>`